# customize-face for display-graphic-p only

Tags: init-file, faces, display

I run graphical [GNU/Emacs on macOS](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/download.html#macos) and also emacs in Mac Terminal [installed via Homebrew](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Installing_Emacs_on_OS_X#Homebrew).

I would like to customize the default face for only the graphical display.

I used `M-x customize-face default`, which produced the following in my `~/.emacs` file

```
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.                                                                                                                                                                
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.                                                                                                                                         
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.                                                                                                                                                
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.                                                                                                                                                    

 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "White" :foreground "Black" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 180 \
:width normal :foundry "nil" :family "Menlo")))))
```

Unfortunately, this configuration also applies to emacs in the Terminal (and makes the background grey for some reason). I do not want the config applied to emacs in the Terminal.

I've read that [display-graphic-p](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Feature-Testing.html) would be a good way to distinguish between my two emacs versions.

How can I modify my `~/.emacs` file to only customize the default face when `display-graphic-p` is true?

I attempted wrapping the inside of custom-set-faces with `(when (display-graphic-p) ... )` but it caused the customization to be lost in both display modes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a face spec that specifies `(graphic)` instead of `t` as the type.  You can use `face-spec-set` to do this.

See the Elisp manual, node [Defining Faces](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Faces.html).